# Get sum of a column in a DF1 based on date range from DF2 in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes and I want to get `sum` of `value` in the dataframe 1 based on the date range from dataframe 2 (`startDate` and `endDate`) and sort the results from maximum to minimum in `Spark`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.to_date

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("2019-01-01", 100), ("2019-01-02", 150),
  ("2019-01-03", 120), ("2019-01-04", 38),
  ("2019-01-05", 200), ("2019-01-06", 381),
  ("2019-01-07", 220), ("2019-01-08", 183),
  ("2019-01-09", 160), ("2019-01-10", 109),
  ("2019-01-11", 130), ("2019-01-12", 282),
  ("2019-01-13", 10), ("2019-01-14", 348),
  ("2019-01-15", 20), ("2019-01-16", 190)
  )).toDF("date", "value").withColumn("date", to_date($"date"))

val df_dates = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("2019-01-01", "2019-01-04"), 
  ("2019-01-05", "2019-01-08"), 
  ("2019-01-09", "2019-01-12"),
  ("2019-01-13", "2019-01-16")
  )).toDF("startDate", "endDate").withColumn("startDate", to_date($"startDate")).withColumn("endDate", to_date($"endDate"))
```

The resulting output will add a column to the `df_date` dataframe `sum_value`. I really do not know where to start. I searched web and couldm't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to join date values to the date ranges, then aggregate:

```
df_dates
  .join(df, $"date".between($"startDate", $"endDate"), "left")
  .groupBy($"startDate", $"endDate").agg(
     sum($"value").as("sum_value")
 )
  .orderBy($"sum_value".desc)
  .show()

+----------+----------+---------+
| startDate|   endDate|sum_value|
+----------+----------+---------+
|2019-01-05|2019-01-08|      984|
|2019-01-09|2019-01-12|      681|
|2019-01-13|2019-01-16|      568|
|2019-01-01|2019-01-04|      408|
+----------+----------+---------+
```